# Lowest sum - Describe the Path

Tags: python

[image]I´m solving an exercise  about the Lowest Sum Matrix problem with Dynamic Programming. But the problem is asking the description of the path that correspond to the sum determined. Does anyone have a solution?

in the example should be
[[1,1], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [3,3], [3,4], [4,4], [5,4], [5,5]]

Here I posted the code I have until now:  https://github.com/jucav-145/saudades-de-casa/blob/main/Lowest%20Sum%20on%20a%20Matrix

EDIT: sorry, i think you already realized I´m kinda new at this.

Comment: Just store a list of the path at each node.  So in your `costs` store a tuple of the min cost and the min path so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to your github example; easy enough to generalize to other matrix sizes.

It tracks the costs and path of points seen but not yet moved from, and only moves from the point with the minimum cost at any point in time.  The list is sorted after each move, and the previous cheapest so far point is removed and the 2 moves from that point are added back into the list.  This is ok because the cost of arriving at a point is the same regardless of direction and all points have non-negative costs, so the first time you reach any point it must be the cheapest path.

```
from copy import copy

matrix = [[131, 673, 234, 103, 18],
[201, 96, 342, 965, 150],
[630, 803, 746, 422, 111],
[537, 699, 497, 121, 956],
[805, 732, 524, 37, 331]]

paths = [(131, [(0,0)])]

while True:
    cost, path = paths.pop()
    last_y, last_x = path[-1]

    if last_x < 4:
        across_cost = cost + matrix[last_y][last_x+1]
        (across_path := copy(path)).append((last_y, last_x+1))
        paths.append((across_cost, across_path))
        if (4,4) == across_path[-1]:
            break

    if last_y < 4:
        down_cost = cost + matrix[last_y+1][last_x]
        (down_path := copy(path)).append((last_y+1, last_x))
        paths.append((down_cost, down_path))
        if (4,4) == down_path[-1]:
            break

    paths.sort(reverse=True)

print(*(path for path in paths if (4,4) == path[1][-1]))
```

Output:

```
(2427, [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (4, 4)])
```

Removing the walrus...

```
while True:
    cost, path = paths.pop()
    last_y, last_x = path[-1]

    if last_x < 4:
        across_cost = cost + matrix[last_y][last_x+1]
        # (across_path := copy(path)).append((last_y, last_x+1))
        across_path = copy(path)
        across_path.append((last_y, last_x+1))
        paths.append((across_cost, across_path))
        if (4,4) == across_path[-1]:
            break

    if last_y < 4:
        down_cost = cost + matrix[last_y+1][last_x]
        # (down_path := copy(path)).append((last_y+1, last_x))
        down_path = copy(path)
        down_path.append((last_y+1, last_x))
        paths.append((down_cost, down_path))
        if (4,4) == down_path[-1]:
            break

    paths.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: It looks great, thank you. But the ':=' is not recognized by Python (I´m using Google Colab right now).